# Sql - how to keep a column not impacted by the group by

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

```
DocumentNames   Path    LastUploadedDate
DOCUMENT 1      PATH1   1/2/2018
DOCUMENT 2      PATH2   1/2/2018
DOCUMENT 1      PATH3   1/4/2018
```

I would like to retrieve, for each document, the path where was saved the document for the last time.

If i do like below, i get 2 rows related to document1

```
SELECT DocumentNames, Path, max(LastUploadedDate)
FROM table1
Group by DocumentNames, Path
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance and kind regards
Cedric

Comment: BTW, I'd chose DocumentName instead as column name. Since a single name is stored, not several names.

Answer (score 0):

use coreleted subquery

```
   select t1.* from table_name t1 where
    t1.LastUploadedDate=(select max(LastUploadedDate)
    from table_name t2 where t1.DocumentNames=t2.DocumentNames
                         )
```

Or you can use window function row_number which support most dbms

```
select * from 

(select *,row_number() over(partition by DocumentNames order by LastUploadedDate desc) rn from table_name
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an inner join on max date

```
select m.* from my_table m 
inner join (
  select  DocumentNames, max(LastUploadedDate) max_date
  from my_table  
  group by DocumentNames 
) t on t.max_date = m.LastUploadedDate and t.DocumentNames = m.DocumentNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `IN` version, where the sub-query returns all DocumentNames together with their max LastUploadedDate.

```
select * from tablename
where (DocumentNames, LastUploadedDate) IN
    (select DocumentNames, max(LastUploadedDate)
     from tablename
     group by DocumentNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DocumentNames, Path, LastUploadedDate
  FROM Table1 A
 WHERE LastUploadedDate = (SELECT MAX(LastUploadedDate)
                             FROM Table1 B
                            WHERE A.DocumentNames = B.DocumentNames)
```

You can use a sub query to return the largest date in the document. Hope this helps.